# Puzzle creator looking for feedback!

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, pattern

I've been an amateur puzzle maker for a long time. I've never really found an audience and someone suggested that I check this place out. My puzzles are kind of ARG style. Let's see if you can figure out this one. Please leave feedback below as well. All I can say is that the answer will be clearly stated.

[image: the puzzle]

> As you might be able to see, there are 3 components to this, separate them.

> The spiralling numbers are for aesthetic but the crossed out boxes are not

> The numbers in the 4 by 4 grid follow a pattern and the number on the bottom right wouldn't be 16

> The pattern for the 4 by 4 square is indeed 1 being one space away from 2, 2 being 2 spaces away from 3. Etc. Wouldn't it be fun to generalize the problem?

> The playfair square goes left to right, top to bottom

Comment: I don't think the [tag:puzzle-creation] tag is applicable here, but that said, this puzzle looks nice!

Comment: What does "ARG style" mean?

Comment: @JamalSenjaya Alternate Reality Game, maybe?

Comment: Indeed that's what I mean. Also I felt puzzle creation was applicable due to me wanting advice.

Comment: This looks like a 15-puzzle, but it's not actually solvable.  Per [this formula](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html), it is an even-width grid, and the blank is in the last row, which means there has to be an even number of inversions to be solvable, but there's actually 41.  It's also reminiscent of a magic square, but there aren't enough numbers around the edge for that.

Comment: No not quite, would you guys like a hint?

Comment: Is the formatting outside of grid intentional?
From top row, I infer it looks like 4 numbers. Is that same case with left, right and bottom side? [In which case, I will like the numbers, as they are hard to parse from the grid]

Or in other case, is this formatting intentional.. with numbers seemingly running into multiple rows and columns?

Comment: Hm? I feel like it's obvious to interpret but I'll give you those numbers. 17267, 2008, 18877, 20793, 16078, 15177, 5254, 20689, 21959, 5046, 18786, 12321, 16637

Comment: Anyone still in on this?

Comment: @Quadraxus That's what I meant, There are just 13 numbers, whereas I was thinking that there would be 16 numbers, 4 per direction. 
So, obviously I was interpreting it wrong

Comment: @Quadraxus - I think it's time for a hint, because this is clearly too obtuse. No one has even posted a first-step answer.

Comment: @Bobson How do I make a hint? Like the uh text hiding way?

Comment: @Quadraxus Yes. Conventionally hints are hidden in spoiler

Comment: Ok uh lemme try and make one

Comment: Uh can you do that? Sorry.....

Comment: It's unclear what the objective of the puzzle is. Is it to fill in the box in the bottom-right corner with an appropriate number?

Comment: The answer is a word

Comment: @Quadraxus Some numbers in split tiles are completely crossed out, others are clearly on one side of the line, possibly indicating(in addition to what you said below) that some squares contain more than one number. Some squares are almost in a split position (eg 2) but not quite, is this intentional?

Comment: below he said "The pattern continues past 16 and the first number in the bottom right isn't 0 or 16"

Comment: No, I tried to center the numbers but it didn't exactly work

Comment: I apologize if this is obtuse, I thought it was difficult yet logical, can you please tell me how to make it uh better?

Comment: >! 1 is not 1 space away from 2, it is 2 spaces away from it (judging by some other spaces) unless your intent is to show that the grid is not properly laid out in its current state?

Comment: I meant an empty space my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]
Uh I'm sorry guys. All I wanted was advice I guess I should just not bother with making puzzles. I never found an audience and everyone seems to hate them....

You separated the 3 components and eventually found USEINTINSTEAD, what you then had to do was use the INT() function. MOD uses the remainder of a quotient, and INT uses the integer part of the quotient. Do that and you get 539, 62, 589, 649, 502, 474, 164, 646, 686, 157, 587, 385, 519. INT those by 32 and we get 16 1 18 20 15 14 5 20 21 4 18 12 16. Translate this via A=1 B=2.... to get PART ONE TUDRLP. MOD those by 32 and translate them same way you did and we get O/P A Q/R T T W/X O/P H/I N D/E B/C A S. You may have to do a little bit of guess work but you can see that it starts off with PART TWO H/I N D/E B/C A S, you may have to do a little bit of experimentation but given what you know you will find out it is a brick wall for thunderclaps. IE put part one on top of part two and read down left to right.

Comment: Why do you think people hate them?

Comment: Sorry I uh tried getting my puzzles to some audiences and they hated them. I don't exactly have self esteem

Comment: I can't read your handwriting - would you mind typing up a clearer explanation?

Comment: @Quadraxus "It would be a shame to just let this peter out, because I think there are some good concepts in the puzzle."    "This puzzle looks nice!"    and a score of 7. People don't hate your puzzles. Just because a puzzle is hard or unintuitive in places doesn't mean that people don't like it. Once you know the answer to a puzzle, it's hard to gauge the difficulty of it. Don't feel bad.

Comment: don't be disheartened if some of your efforts seem to not succeed - https://justbereal.co.uk/7-celebrities-who-started-out-with-poor-self-esteem/

Comment: Don't stop making puzzles, please. In fact, post more and more here. Those who "hate" them probably do not enjoy puzzles that cause someone to really think. As you see here, the community was getting close to a solution. Keep up the good work, and I'd love to see a book of puzzles from you one day, even if I may not be able to solve them all.

Comment: Um basically the you were close up to USEINTINSTEAD Int is the opposite of mod as in 47mod7 is 5 and 47int7 is 6 because it's the integer part of the uh answer. You get more numbers. If you mod32 the numbers and translate you get part one t u/v d/e q/r l o/p  if you int32 the numbers you get in a=1, b=2 you get part two hnecas. This is a brick wall reading thunderclaps. Thunderclaps is the answer.

Comment: So yeah I put this in puzzle design because I thought this was obvious (obvious yet difficult), I felt like you didn't really have to make any leaps in logic but then again I set the puzzle and I have Asperger's so I think differently. Oh uh sorry I shouldn't have said that should I.....

Comment: Yeah, I've overestimated difficulty of puzzles before too. It happens a lot - I use PSE to help myself gauge difficulty better. Anyway, I can't understand your explanation at all - would you mind explaining more clearly? (You can edit it into this answer.)

Comment: Uh what don't you understand?

Comment: @Quadraxus: this seems to be a decent puzzle, and the response to it was great too. The PSE community got pretty close to solving it, which is an indicator that difficulty-wise you're in the ballpark. You could help clarify your answer by typing out what you wrote - we don't all read handwriting that well. Thanks!

Comment: @Quadraxus I did enjoy the puzzle though the solution was likely out of my reach as mathematics is not my strong suit. Seemed like some of the other members were getting there though. Keep the puzzles coming.

Comment: I can see how you get "thunderclaps", but now do you get "brick wall"?

Answer (score 6):

**Update**, but still not even a partial answer, I'm afraid. I'm just thinking aloud and throw out some ideas.

What is the missing number?

> AstroMax has found the actual pattern: the number *n* comes *n* places after the previous number, *n* − 1. This pattern uases the rows as lines and it wraps when the bottom right is reached.
>
>  This pattern can be continued until a number is placed in the last cell, which is 31. The next step would place a 32 in the same box, and by now, every cell has exactly two numbers:
>
>  [image: two numbers per cell]
>
>  The pattern can be continued infinitely, of course.

What is the meaning of the diagonal bars?

> There are sixteen cells overall and ten of them are divided by a diagonal bar. That makes six full cells and 20 half-cells. That's 26 cells in total, which conveniently is the number of English letters. Hmm.
>
>  My guess was that each cell referred to a letter. Meanwhile, the OP has stated that the grid is a Playfair square. Typically, Playfair uses a 5×5 grid for the 26 english letters. The excess letter is taken care of by rtreating two letters – typically I and J, less frequently U and V – as equal.
>
>  Apparently, the present grid combines nine more letters to equal pairs. The hint says that the Playfair grid goes from left to right and from top to bottom. There doesn't seem to be a keyword, so one possibility could be:
>
>  [image: possible letter pattern]

What are the numbers around the perimeter for?

> The OP has disclosed that the answer is a word. There are thirteen numbers. The Playfair cipher works with pairs of letters. If there is an odd number of letters, there must be padding. This doesn't really fit, but perhaps "Playfair" doesn't refer to the Playfair cipher, only to the practice of pairing letters.
>
>  Continuing the pattern above, so that all of the thirteen numbers are assigned a cell, we get:
>
>  17267 → 14: U or V
>  2008 → 12: S
>  18877 → 3: D or E
>  20793 → 5: H or I
>  16078 → 9: N
>  15177 → 13: T
>  5254 → 5: H or I
>  20689 → 9: N
>  21959 → 12: S
>  5046 → 13: T
>  18786 → 3: D or E
>  12321 → 1: A
>  16637 → 3: D or E
>
>  The numbers after the arrows are the cell numbers, starting with 1, 2, 3, and 4 from left to right in the top row and ending with 16 in the bottom right. The letters correspond to the scheme I've posted above, which isn't established at all. That result doesn't look promising. There is a good share of vowels, however, so maybe we should build an anagram? Nah, that would be devious.

Comment: To add to the pattern with 0 in the bottom corner, each row and each column contains 2 odds and 2 evens, in the rows the sum of the evens is 2 less than the sum of the odds

Comment: With the premise that the grid goes 0-15 instead of 1-16, then when solved as a sliding puzzle the blank should be in the upper left corner, which **is** solvable, unlike in [my previous comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55444/puzzle-creator-looking-for-feedback-try-this-tough-one-game-giveaway-to-first#comment171003_55444).  May or may not be relevant.

Comment: You're right there is a playfair square! But you're interpreting it wrong. The pattern continues past 16 and the first number in the bottom right isn't 0 or 16, it's larger than 16

Comment: 31 would be logical as the last number. No idea what to do with that, though.

Comment: @HughMeyers: Yes, with the pattern that AstroMax found I get 31, too. When I get there, every other cell has exactly two numbers.

Comment: Agreed, 31 makes a much better fit with the pattern. I think your idea of substituting the numbers in the box with letters makes a lot of sense aswell. I wonder if maybe the letters should replace the numbers in cronological order instead, ex: 1 is A, 2 is B/C, 3 being D/E and so on. I like where your going with this, good show.

Comment: Correct! Now you are done the first part! You need to interpret it though

Comment: "That result doesn't look promising" Doesn't your result spell "USE INT INSTEAD"? No idea what that's supposed to mean but it does look promising to me.

Comment: @SirGrapefruit: Well spotted! I didn't see that, because I was looking for a single word. (Somewhere buried in the comments to the question, OP says that the answer is a word.) I'm told to "interpret" the result, so maybe the phrase you found is just an intermediate step. I'm not sure, what INT in this context means, though.

Comment: My guess would be that INT is short for Integer and that there are some numbers hidden in binary/hexadecimal/whatever and you'd have to convert them to decimal (and then to characters using the square?). That doesn't seem to give any results though.

Comment: I'd considered that int could be integers, but why "instead"? We've used integers all along. Using the integers from the pattern or the cell positions as letters (1=A, 2=B, C=3, ..., 26=Z) doesn't yield anything useful.

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how you were able to assign the 13 numbers to the lettered cells? You mentioned using the pattern to do so but im having some trouble seeing how.

Comment: My apologies should I just give the answer seeing how I'm so terrible at this......

Comment: @AstroMax: It's your pattern, applied up to 21959. The image in the post shows where each of the numbers from 1 to 32 wold be placed. You can continue infinitely. 21959 is placed 21959 mod 16 == 7 places after 21958 and it ends up in cell number 12. Because the numbers are so large it's hard to visualise. Of course, I didn't calculate this by hand; I wrote a small script to do it for me.

Comment: @Quadraxus: Judging the difficulty of puzzles is hard, and solving this one up to its current state was a bit of a piecemeal process where confirmation of the steps had to come explicitly from you. If you think you've made a mistake so that it can't be solved or that the next step requires too big a leap of logic, you can post the intended answer to your own question. It would be a shame to just let this peter out, because I think there are some good concepts in the puzzle.

Comment: Uh I guess I'll wait a week

Comment: @MOehm After reading your post again it does seem pretty clear how you assigned the cells. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial Answer**

Using the hint given which suggests there is three parts to the puzzle, a potential answer to the one part may be.

> 24. In the box if you start at #1 counting in order (ie 1,2,3,4,5 etc.) towards the right, then continuing counting on the rows below, a pattern seems to emerge. Starting at 1 the number 2 is two boxes away (not counting the box you start on). If you count from 2 to 3 the number 3 three is three boxes away. From 3 to 4 four boxes away and so on. This pattern continues all the way up to 15.

Hence

> If we follow this pattern counting in order, the amount of boxes away we are from the previous numbered box, we could conclude that the blank box is 8 boxes away. But as the OP commented the number is higher than 16. If the numbers cannot be repeated then you may guess 24. if you count past the blank box as to not repeat the number 8 you would get 24.   **As M Oehm has uncovered, 31 is  much better suited to complete the pattern rather than 24.**

The surrounding numbers

> could possibly be decrypted into a key. The OP mentions playfair in previous comments so a key would prove of useful for a playfair type encryption.

Comment: that's a good reason to place 0 there

Comment: You're on the right track, you found the pattern (although your analysis of it is wrong), so we have a pattern, a playfair square, and some huge numbers. What do you think you should do?

Answer (score -3):

The answer is

> 16

Reasoning is

> the box has the numbers 1-15 without repeating. 16 would complete the box while keeping the sequential pattern. The numbers surrounding the box and the lines inside seem to be just a distraction from the solution.

Comment: No, the other components are obviously a part of the puzzle as well. So no. Also I will give hints if necessary.